# CouchDB - filter latest log per logged instance from a list

Tags: python, couchdb, mapreduce, couchdbkit

I could use some help filtering distinct values from a couchdb view.
I have a database that stores logs with information about computers.
Periodically new logs for a computer are written to the db.

A bit simplified i store entries like these:

```
{
   "name": "NAS",
   "os": "Linux",
   "timestamp": "2011-03-03T16:26:39Z",
}
{
   "name": "Server1",
   "os": "Windows",
   "timestamp": "2011-02-03T19:31:31Z",
}
{
   "name": "NAS",
   "os": "Linux",
   "timestamp": "2011-02-03T18:21:29Z",
}
```

So far i am struggling to filter this list by distinct entries.
What i'd like to receive is the latest logfile for each device.

I have a view like this:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.timestamp,doc.name], doc);
}
```

Im querying this view with python (couchdbkit) and the best solution i came up with so far looks like this:

```
def get_latest_logs(cls):
    unique = []
    for log in cls.view("logs/timestamp", descending=True):
        if log.name not in unique_names:
            unique.append(log)
    return unique
```

Okay ... this works. But i have the strong feeling, that this is not the best solution as python needs to iterate the whole list of logfiles (which could become quite long).

I guess i need a reduce function but i couldn't really find any examples
 or explanations that i could adapt to my problem.

So, what i am looking for is a (pure couchdb) view, that only spits out the latest log for a given device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I do. This is borderline CouchDB abuse however I have had much success.

Usually, `reduce` will compute a sum, or a count, or something like that. However, think of reduce as an elimination tournament. Many values go in. Only one comes out. A reduction! Repeat over and over and you have the ultimate winner (a re-reduction). In this case, the log with the latest timestamp is the winner.

Of course, welterweights can't fight heavyweights. There have to be leagues and weight classes. It only makes sense for *certain* documents to do battle with *certain other* similar documents. That is exactly what the reduce **group** parameter will do. It will ensure that only evenly-matched gladiators enter the steel cage in our bloodsport. (Coffee is kicking in.)

First, emit all logs keyed by device. The `value` emitted is simply a copy of the document.

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.name, doc);
}
```

Next, write a reduce function to return the latest timestamp of all given values. If you see a fight between two gladiators from different leagues (two logs from different systems), stop the fight! Something went wrong (somebody queried without the correct `group` value).

```
function(keys, vals, re) {
    var challenger, winner = null;
    for(var a = 0; a < vals.length; a++) {
        challenger = vals[a];
        if(!winner) {
            // The title is unchallenged. This value is the winner.
            winner = challenger;
        } else {
            // Fight!
            if(winner.name !== challenger.name) {
                // Stop the fight! He's gonna kill him!
                return null; // With a grouping query, this will never happen.
            } else if(winner.timestamp > challenger.timestamp) {
                // The champ wins! (Nothing to do.)
            } else {
                // The challenger wins!
                winner = challenger;
            }
        }
    }

    // Today's champion lives to fight another day.
    return winner;
}
```

(Note, the timestamp comparison is probably wrong. You will have to convert to a `Date` probably.)

Now, when you query a view with `?group=true`, then CouchDB will only reduce (find the winner between) values with the same `key`, which is your machine name.

(You can also emit an array as a key, which gives a bit more flexibility. You could `emit([doc.name, doc.timestamp], doc)` instead. So you can see all logs by system with a query like `?reduce=false&startkey=["NAS", null]&endkey=["NAS", {}]` or you could see latest logs by system with `?group_level=1`.

Finally, the "stop the fight" stuff is optional. You could simply always return the document with the latest timestamp. However, I prefer to keep it there because in similar situations, I want to see if I am map-reducing incorrectly, and a null reduce output is my big clue.

Comment: Thank you. That works great. And what a nice cinematographic answer :-)


P.S. I'll give it an upvote as soon as i can ;-)