# Couchdb map/reduce to return the first in a stream, then order by time

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have a couchdb which holds a series of events.  Each event has an owner, an id, a time it occured and a message (plus a bunch of other stuff which doesn't matter for this exercise).  I'd like a list of events which occured recently ordered by time.  I looked through this question [CouchDB - filter latest log per logged instance from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198023/couchdb-filter-latest-log-per-logged-instance-from-a-list) and tried using it with the comparison in the reducer flipped to keep the first message (using the form where I have a complex key).

Unfortunately it doesn't quite seem to do what want.

Here's my map function

```
function(doc) {
  var owner, id;
  if (doc.owner
      && doc.stream_id
      && doc.message
      && doc.receipt_time)
    {
      emit([doc.owner,doc.stream_id,doc.receipt_time],
           { owner: doc.owner,
             stream_id: doc.stream_id,
             timestamp: doc.receipt_time,
             message: doc.message
           });
    }
}
```

and my reduce function

```
function(keys, values) {
  var challenger, winner = null;
  for (var a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
      challenger = values[a];
      if (! winner) {
        winner = challenger;
      } else {
        if (winner.owner !== challenger.owner
            && winner.trace_id !== challenger.trace_id ) {
          return null;
        } else if (challenger.timestamp < winner.timestamp) {
          winner = challenger;
        }
      }
    }
  return winner;
}
```

Then I invoke with ?descending=true&group=true&group_level=2 to get the first message from each stream, however, it doesn't seem to be ordered by time, but by owner and stream_id, like this

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":["sam","a"],
   "value":
     {"owner":"sam","stream_id":"a","timestamp":1303754236482,"message":"foo"}
  },
  {"key":["sam","b"],
   "value":
     {"owner":"sam","stream_id":"b","timestamp":1303752578476,"message":"bar"}
  },
  {"key":["jim","j1"],
   "value":
     {"owner":"jim","stream_id":"j1","timestamp":1303625378839,"message":"stuff"}
  },
  {"key":["bob","loblaw"],
   "value":
     {"owner":"bob","stream_id":"loblaw","timestamp":1303328396532,"message":"more stuff"}
  },
  {"key":["anthony","foo"],
   "value":
     {"owner":"anthony","stream_id":"foo","timestamp":1303769699444,"message":"even more"}
  }
]}
```

(Notice the final entry actually is the most recent in time).

So what I'd like is for the final view to be what it is now but ordered by time.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Store stream_created_at timestamp in every message. So for the first message you take current time. For every next message in the stream you copy it from the previous one (create a view to get stream_created_at_by_stream_id for this).

Then create view that emits:

```
[doc.owner,doc.stream_created_at, doc.stream_id, doc.receipt_time]
```

That will group messages from the same stream together while preserving time ordering. stream.id will ensure that messages from different streams don't mix up when two streams are created at the same time. And receipt_time will order the messages in the stream by time.

So in the end you will get Facebook like conversations. And you don't need any reduce function at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're not looking to filter the collection of events, but just order them.  Assuming that's correct, the solution is actually pretty simple and you don't even need a reduce function.  The keys that are emitted in your map function are used to sort the view, first by what's first in the key, then working the rest of the way through it.  In other words, if you want to sort by stream_id then receipt_time, your call to emit would look like this:

```
emit([doc.stream_id,doc.receipt_time,doc.owner], doc.message);
```

Naturally, if you instead want to sort by receipt_time then stream_id, the key would instead be `[doc.receipt_time,doc.stream_id,doc.owner]`.  I don't think there's any need to include anything in the value that's already present in the key, which is why I trimmed the value down to just the message.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding.  For any one owner + stream_id there can be up to several thousand messages.  I want to show the first message in each stream, then order them by timestamp.  If you order them [owner,stream_id,receipt_time], then with group_level 2 and the reduce function I outlined, I get the first message of each stream by owner and stream_id, **but** they are out of order according to time.  If I include receipt_time (ie, group_level 3), I get every message, so that defeats the purpose.

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand. I think there might still be an easier way to do it that would actually work, but I'll have to think about it. Perhaps one of the Couch experts will come along and provide an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the easiest is actually to just avoid the issue.

Since I control the software which sends the events I just added a `"start":true,` field to the first document in the stream, then the view function just emits events with that value.

This means I can't get this for historic data, but that's okay as this is mostly for checking recent streams.

Another alternative I tried was adding a list function which sends the first instance of each owner stream_id, on a view whose key is [timestamp,owner,stream_id], however, that runs into the problem that when you limit it doesn't limit the final rendered list but the original view, so the extra key works best so far).

I would still like to know if there is some way to do this with the original data.